# Recyclerview scroll up destroy my run-time changes

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I face a problem when i change my recylerview one item data like if an item have a textview with number "0". when user perform n action on that item i change that text to "1". after that when user scroll down and scroll up again my run time changes ("0" -> "1") destroy.
I try:
holder.setIsRecyclable(false); but not work.

I add the click listener in ViewHolder and here is the basic code:

```
                public void onClick(View view) {if(!postItem.isIncrease()){
        tvCount.setText(String.valueOf((Integer.parseInt(tvCount.getText().toString())+1)));
    }}
```

Comment: Please add your adapter code as well

Comment: @Parth check the basic code

Comment: No, Not the snippet but the whole adapter

Comment: Change the backing data and notify the adapter, don't change views directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You set your "0" from your data model(atleast I suspect it) and when user updated UI you didn't apply this changes to your data model. In your case it's means when text related to specific viewholder changed you have apply this changes to your item from your list on same position. Then when your will read data from this item again in will be updated.

Comment: I place the click listener in viewholder where 0 change to 1 when user click on any item. Can you give me any example code to apply change in data model to apply this changes to item in list on same position

Comment: Add your code of adapter and VH and I'll correct it.

Comment: Thank you @Eugene Troyanskii i got your answer. After update the data model my problem now solve!